# android dynamic layout with variable textviews and events

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, textview

I have a layout with dynamic content. It has a variable number of textviews. On each textview I have to attach an event, a click event.

I have to pass to that event some kind of information to know what textview has been clicked exactly.

How can I pass this kind of information or how is the android way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onClick(View v)` callback has `View v` on which you can do `.getId()` on. This gives you information about which of the textViews that was clicked.

Comment: thanks, this works. When I dynamically create the textview I will attach a specific id that will help me to determine the future action

Comment: or a better way I guess is to set the tag of that element. there you can store an object